# Error in jQuery DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need a DatePicker element in my page.  I have the below code already in place:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Check Printing";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3>Define Check Batch</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Check Type:</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("list", ViewData["list"] as SelectList)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pay Period:</td>
        <td>12/17/2014 - 01/08/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Check Date:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Starting Check Number:</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#datepicker").each(function () {
                $(this).datepicker();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

However, when i run this code, it gives me the following error:

Unhandled exception at line 126, column 17 in http://localhost:53130/CheckPrinting/CheckPrinting

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

I'm not sure what's happening, everything looks like it's set up right?
Thanks

Edit: Here is the "Dynamic" code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <title>Check Printing - SAAS</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Student Accounting and Allotment System" />
    <link href="/Content/Site.less" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/custom/custom.less" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <!--Masthead-->
    <div class="masthead">
        <!--Utility Bar-->
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-left:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                            <object data="/Content/images/US-JobCorps-Logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="60" height="60" style="float:left; margin-right:5px;"></object>
                            <div style="float:right; margin-top:-20px;">
                                <h2>SAAS</h2>
                                <h6>Student Accounting and Allotment System</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="float:none; margin-top:25px;">John Doe <b class="caret" style="margin-left:20px;"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Main Navigation-->
        <div class="navbar navbar-primary">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-bottom:0px; padding-bottom:0px;">
                        <li><a href='/CheckRegister/CheckRegister'><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Check Register</a></li>
                        <li><a href='/Home/About'><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Reconcile</a></li>
                        <li><a href='/StudentInfo/Info'><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Student Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href='/Home/About'><i class="fa fa-print fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Check Printing</a></li>
                        <li><a href='/Home/About'><i class="fa fa-retweet fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Reissues</a></li>
                        <li><a href='/Home/About'><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Centers</a></li>
                        <li><a href='/Home/About'><i class="fa fa-area-chart fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Reports</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="container-fluid body-content" style="margin-top:-39px;">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<h3>Define Check Batch</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Check Type:</td>
        <td><select id="list" name="list"><option value="0">- Select -</option>
<option value="1">Payroll</option>
<option value="2">Termination</option>
<option value="3">Allotment</option>
<option value="4">Bonus</option>
</select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pay Period:</td>
        <td>12/17/2014 - 01/08/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Check Date:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Starting Check Number:</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>


        <hr />
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>






    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#datepicker").each(function () {
                $(this).datepicker();
            });
        });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - SAAS</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Student Accounting and Allotment System" />
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <!--Masthead-->
    <div class="masthead">
        <!--Utility Bar-->
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-left:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                            <object data="~/Content/images/US-JobCorps-Logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="60" height="60" style="float:left; margin-right:5px;"></object>
                            <div style="float:right; margin-top:-20px;">
                                <h2>SAAS</h2>
                                <h6>Student Accounting and Allotment System</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="float:none; margin-top:25px;">John Doe <b class="caret" style="margin-left:20px;"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Main Navigation-->
        <div class="navbar navbar-primary">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-bottom:0px; padding-bottom:0px;">
                        <li class="@Url.MakeActive("", "CheckRegister")"><a href='@Url.Action("CheckRegister","CheckRegister")'><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Check Register</a></li>
                        <li class="@Url.MakeActive("About", "Home")"><a href='@Url.Action("About","Home")'><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Reconcile</a></li>
                        <li class="@Url.MakeActive("Student")"><a href='@Url.Action("Info","StudentInfo")'><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Student Info</a></li>
                        <li class="@Url.MakeActive("About", "Home")"><a href='@Url.Action("About","Home")'><i class="fa fa-print fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Check Printing</a></li>
                        <li class="@Url.MakeActive("About", "Home")"><a href='@Url.Action("About","Home")'><i class="fa fa-retweet fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Reissues</a></li>
                        <li class="@Url.MakeActive("About", "Home")"><a href='@Url.Action("About","Home")'><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Centers</a></li>
                        <li class="@Url.MakeActive("About", "Home")"><a href='@Url.Action("About","Home")'><i class="fa fa-area-chart fa-fw fa-inverse"></i> Reports</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="container-fluid body-content" style="margin-top:-39px;">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dataTables")*@
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom")*@
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/StudentAllotments")*@

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what server-side or templating language that is, but can you post the rendered HTML only? Also, why bother looping with .each() on your datepicker ID as IDs must be unique?

Comment: @j08691 ahh, good call on that ID!  I found that piece of the code online somewhere and forgot to get rid of the for each part.  I just added the "dynamic" HTML to the bottom of the post.  Thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding two (different) copies of jQuery to the same page? Also, why aren't all your scripts and styles in the head of the page?

Comment: All of his scripts should be at the end of the body.

Comment: @j08691 Neither of those have any effect on my code, because I have the exact same thing in the other pages of my site (this is the general template we're using for each page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine here.

I used your code in this example, just remove a lot of the menu stuff to keep it simple.  If this example is not working for you, then it may be an error specific to your development environment and/or browser.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<h3>Define Check Batch</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Check Type:</td>
        <td><select id="list" name="list"><option value="0">- Select -</option>
<option value="1">Payroll</option>
<option value="2">Termination</option>
<option value="3">Allotment</option>
<option value="4">Bonus</option>
</select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pay Period:</td>
        <td>12/17/2014 - 01/08/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Check Date:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Starting Check Number:</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm assuming that you're using Visual Studio (based on your code) - there's a lot of options to be able to debug your code and see exactly where the error is happening.

Check simple things - make sure jQuery is loaded first before jQuery UI, jQuery should only be loaded one time on the page.  Are there scripts interfering with jQuery in some way?  If all of these are okay, then start inserting breakpoints and step through it until you find the problem.

If you can create a fiddle or a snippet that reproduces your exact problem, then I'd be happy to look into it further for you, but without being on your machine - I can't reproduce this problem that you're having.

Comment: okay, this really makes no sense, because I'm still getting the same error. I'm using Visual Studio and (unfortunately) Internet Explorer.  The error that it is throwing-that the Object doesn't support the "datepicker" property or method- happens on the " $("#datepicker").datepicker(); " line

Comment: Try to assign a variable to the jQuery datepicker element, like so `var datePicker = $("#datepicker");`  then set a breakpoint on something like `console.log(datePicker);`.  When you hover over your variable in Visual Studio, you should be able to see a lot of details about that jQuery object.  This may help you track down where the problem is originating from.

Comment: So something like this?

$(document).ready(function () { var datePicker = $("#datepicker");            console.log(datePicker); $("#datepicker").datepicker(); });
?

Comment: Yeah, something like that, but set your breakpoint in Visual Studio on `console.log(datePicker)`  This will allow you to see all of the properties of the jQuery object and should help you track down the problem.

Comment: I just tried that, and it's skipping over the breakpoint.  It says: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Comment: Did you save and reload the page?  If the breakpoint isn't being hit, then something else is going on...

Comment: Yes, I did... I'll post a pic in the original post of what shows up at the breakpoint when I try to run it with the breakpoint... I'm totally stumped... Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just added it to the original post

Comment: I'm kinda at a loss here.  Everything looks okay to me.

Comment: Okay, thanks, thats what I was thinking, it makes no sense...  Is there another option for this kind of thing that you could point me to that might work?

Comment: I would probably start a new project from scratch and just put in the bare minimum necessary to get the datepicker working.  Once you get it working in the new project, start bringing over pieces of your current project, little by little.  If something breaks your datepicker, then you have found your culprit.  Just my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just do that, it should work :

`$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker();
 });`

Since `#datepicker` is an id

Comment: Ok, in your "Dynamic" code, you load JQuery two times, may be that this poses problems.
One time with `<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>` and second time with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`